# Chrome extension to merge windows?

Tags: osx, chrome

I'd sometimes end up with two Chrome windows with multiple tabs on each. While I do this intentionally at first, I usually end up with no good distinction between them and want them to all be in the same window.

Right now I have to manually drag each and every tab across from the old window to the new window. This is quite a lot of work and I don't like it.

OS  X's Terminal app has an awesome option to do this:

[image]

Ideally, I'd have an option in the Window menu like this for Chrome, although that's probably very difficult to do with a userscript/extension.

What it needs to do:

- Work with multiple windows with multiple tabs each (of course)
- Give me a button to merge two (or ideally more, though a max of two is fine) windows
- Be *fairly* user-friendly. By this I mean that I don't really want to go fiddle around in the command line. I want a button.

Is there an extension/app that does this?

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you do a group select with `SHIFT` (i.e. clicking first tab selection, then last with shift; that will select all of the tabs in between)? Then, you can drag those to another window. Yes, an extension might be easier, but sometimes it's nice to keep things simple.

Comment: Because one click is better than five, @Annon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension should do - multiple tabs and multiple windows, simple button, no options (user-friendly):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-windows/adjadgadeebehakpgamlnafmdkegkmph

You may have a different opinion, so just look on the related tab when you click the link if you don't like it

An alternative: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/join-windows/bckmemeadiidpmgdfcimoclbbhfpjggb